# Rails view is not getting updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a button click that triggers the following function. It calls the below asynchronous request.

```
    <script>
        function buy_now(user_id, deal_id) {
            var purchase_confirmed = confirm("Are you sure you want to make this purchase?");
            var theUrl = "/orders/create?user_id=" + user_id + "&deal_id=" + deal_id;  
            if(purchase_confirmed){
                var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, true ); // true for asynchronous request
                xmlHttp.send( null );
                return xmlHttp.responseText;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

orders_controller.rb

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @order = Order.new(user_id: orders_params[:user_id], deal_id: orders_params[:deal_id])

        unless @order.save
            url = "/deals/today_deal?user_id=" + orders_params[:user_id] 
            redirect_to url, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end 
    end

    private
    def orders_params
        params.permit(:user_id, :deal_id)
    end
end
```

create.html.erb

```
<h1> Order successful </h1>
```

routes.rb

```
ails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'deals#today_deal'

  get '/deals', to: 'deals#index'
  get '/deals/today', to: 'deals#today_deal'
  get '/deals/new', to: 'deals#new'
  get '/deals/:id', to: 'deals#show'
  post '/deals/create', to: 'deals#create'

  get '/orders/create', to: 'orders#create'

  #set all incorrect paths to go to the root path
  match '*path' => redirect('/'), via: :get
end
```

The problem is that once the create action(shown above) in the orders_controller is called and the subsequent view(shown above) is rendered the screen is not updated with the new view. I understand that I don't understand some concept here. It would great if you could point me to some resources to understand what I am doing wrong here. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The create method likely takes a POST request, not a GET, so it isn't going to return that view you created there unless you direct it to that, make sure you have a GET request in your routes to direct to that  though.  So when you hit that create method you still need to tell it what to show on a successful save.  Right now you only have a condition that renders when the save fails.  It might be better to use an if/else here, if the order saves do this, else do what you have in there now

Comment: @RockwellRice I have updated the question to have the routes.rb file. Its not a POST request, its a GET. Any  other ideas?

As for the second point. I put the view rendered for an unsuccessful save. If its successful it would just go to create.html.erb and render that view right?

Comment: Not unless you tell it to do that.  I guess I am still a little confused on the expected behavior.  You hit a button it triggers that JS, and is that suppose to redirect to the create template, is that the idea?  If you look in you log file, what routes are being hit when you run this process?

Comment: Hint: In Rails you would define the route as `post '/deals', to: 'deals#create'`. The "verb" isn't actually a part of the URL in Rails except for the `new` and `edit` actions that are just used to render forms. Everything else is done with the HTTP verbs.  I mean you can do it that way - it will just make you look like the FNG. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

Comment: Apart from that your expectations here are completely wrong. When you send an asyncronous request a redirect won't actually cause the browser to automatically navigate to another page. You actually have to deal with the response in your ajax handler and redirect the user by setting `window.location`. All that will happen here is nothing. I would really start by just setting this up as a normal (syncronous) form and focus on learning Rails first.

Comment: @max Thanks for the tip on the naming conventions. I will make sure to follow that.
As for your suggestion about the synchronous form. Can you tell me specifically what the code would look like, I have tried making a synchronous form and it gives me the same results. If possible it would be great if you can give a small explanation along with a code snippet.